# Can't build atom on Linux

Tags: linux, atom-editor

I followed these [steps](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md) to build atom on Linux on my own.

After cloning atom, i tried to run `script/build`.
 But i get an error `"No such file or directory"`.

Node v0.10.31
Npm v0.10.31

I don't now how can I run these atom-build-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, i found a solution to fix this issue.

[1] after installing node via **apt**, its command is `nodejs`, not `node` like its recommended to use these build-script 
[1.1] after removing apt's node installation, i [build](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installation#building-on-gnulinux-and-other-unix) node by my own
[2] run `which node`, to find out where you install node
[3] to run the build-script: `/opt/node/bin/node your-atom-path/script/build`

additional information how to fix from [atom-github-build-instructions](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md#usrbinenv-node-no-such-file-or-directory)
*"/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
If you get this notice when attempting to script/build, you either do not have Node.js installed, or node isn't identified as Node.js on your machine. If it's the latter, entering sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node into your terminal may fix the issue."*